# How can I get favorites_count according to my searched words using by Twitter Api?

Tags: php, twitter

I want to calculate favorite_count when I searched a word in twitter. I am using Twitter api in PHP and now, I can search words successfully. Also, I can calculate retweet count.

But I could't find ant way to get favorites_count. Here is a link for help: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/favorites

Answer (score 0):

have a look in the [twitter faq](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/faq#finding-counting-things)

> How do I count favorites?
>
> The number of times a tweet was favorited is now available as part of tweet objects in the REST, Streaming, and Search APIs -- you'll find it presented in the "favorite_count" field.
>
> Additionally, User streams and Site streams both stream events when an authenticated user favorites tweets or has their tweets favorited. Using these authenticated streaming APIs, you can count favorites in real-time as they happen.